# How to Design a Metric from DTW

Tags: metric-spaces, dynamic-programming

I am trying to get a feeling for how to design metrics. Here I want to ask about designing a metric from Dynamic Time Warping distance (DTW).

Let's say I want to develop a metric for continuous sequences similar to DTW. As it is well known DTW is not a metric, since it does not fulfill the triangular inequality and sequences which are different might still have distance of 0 to each other. Which design patterns / recepiece / methods / tricks exist, to make sure, the DTW does become a metric? How should I approach the issue (without being a genius or waiting for a lucky epiphany)?

One way to approach this, would be that any warping, adds some distance between the two sequences. So only if I need to warp one of the sequences to and receive 0 distance regarding the sequence values, I still get distance, because of the warping.

Now I am only left with the fact that the triangular inequality might not be fulfilled. As a reminder: the total DTW distance is the sum of squares of all the distances of the values of each match. Here I could suggest that instead of using the squares of difference for a match, one could simply just use the absolute value of the difference.

I am not sure whether I got a metric now. Is this approach sensible? Is it a metric? How do I discuss this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I will bite.

Why make it a metric? There is a strong case for needing non-metric measures in some cases.

One use of triangular inequality is speeding up search, but DTW search is VERY fast just using lower-bounding-search (UCR-Suite).

As an aside, almost everyone use cDTW, which becomes a metric in the limit as the warping window gets smaller.

https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

Comment: Wow, Keogh himself answered (I mean this completely un-ironic)!! I am familiar with (and impressed by) your work, including, but not limited to the PDF you linked to. I studied and reimplemented the accompanied code of your trillion paper: big fan.

Comment: To the topic: One non-pragmatic reason for my question is because I study the design of metrics in general and this was just one of the examples. More pramatically: 1) I get your point for KNN, but wouldn't the use if the inequality equation further improve the speed or wouldn't that make a difference because we get too rarely that far in the lower bound cascade?

Comment: 2) There are (obviously) other uses of DTW than KNN. For example, I research clustering, especially mean shift like methods, for distances that would be median shift, medoid shift or density peaks. Each if these is at least $O(n^2)$ or even $O(n^3)$ with n being the number of objects (e.g. sequences). Density peaks should be somewhere between, naively at the later, but clever calculation reuses might get it closer to the former. For DTW this would be multipled by $m^2$ with m being the length of the sequence. As far as I understand you managed to get rid of the $m^2$ with the bounds.

Comment: When we calculate the density by kernel density estimation instead of range query though, we require about 40-60% of the distances (see DENCLUE paper), so your bounds are not so helpful. However, by using dual trees we might be able to improve that drastically - but they require a metric... OK, let's we stay with the range query for density estimation. Now we still have the (at least) $n^2$. Fortunately ;-) I am developing a method to solve that problem. While I can manage without the triangular inequality, I could further improve my method in effectiveness and efficiency if I had it.

Comment: I am sure there are other areas where a metric would be useful, but I am mist firm in density clustering. Thoygh this brings me to: 3) In which situations would I not only not care whether it is a metric, but actively *prefer* a non-metric?

Comment: (Embedding the sequences into a multivariate vector space would be another application of having a metric!)